# What is the range of DateTime?

Tags: php, datetime

What is the range of [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) in PHP?

Even though the constructor does not seem to accept values in the `Y-m-d` format outside the `[0-9999]` range, the following works:

Adding 10.000 years:

```php
// 12012-12-12
echo (new DateTime())->add(new DateInterval('P10000Y'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Subtracting 10.000 years:

```php
// -7988-12-12
echo (new DateTime())->sub(new DateInterval('P10000Y'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

I was unable to find this information in the documentation.

Comment: see this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php

> The date and time information is internally stored as a 64-bit number so all conceivably useful dates (including negative years) are supported. The range is from about 292 billion years in the past to the same in the future.

Comment: Looks like I missed the obvious intro. Thanks!

Comment: But it may still be interesting to know that that internal number is not protected from overflow: `'P293000000000Y'` set as an interval value will send you back in time. )

Comment: @raina77ow You're probably using a 32-bit PHP, so your string probably overflows a 32-bit integer in `DateInterval`, not `DateTime`!